# How to Display two atcivitys Ui in one screen 70 % and 30%?

Tags: android, user-interface

How can i display two atcivitys Ui in one screen like one UI should be display 70% and another should be 30% using ViewFlipper.
I am new to android.If any idea please replys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what is view flipper object, but I think what you are asking is Android Fragments

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `Fragments` to achieve the type of layout you want.You can show multiple `Fragments` at the same time, each with their own layout and implementations.

[You can find more info on them here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for this